# Zapier: Pull Data From Two API EndPoints In One Trigger

Tags: zapier

​
I am working on a trigger where I need to pull data from two API end points. The first endpoint is a contact from a database that retrieves an email address, then to obtain the details for that contact (email) I need to use another end point. once is /Subscriber and the other is /Subsriber/ {email}/ Properties.

I am wondering if I can use a variable to obtain all the data in one trigger, as I have is set up in separate triggers right now.

Here is the code for both

Subscriber:

```
  url: 'https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Subscribers?PageSize=1',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  },
  params: {
    'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  }
};


return z.request(options).then((response) => {
 response.throwForStatus();
 const result = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
 result.id = result.Items;
 return [result];
});
```

And Subscriber Properties

```
const options = {
  url: `https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Subscribers/${bundle.inputData.email_address}/Properties`,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  },
  params: {
    'email_address': bundle.inputData.email_address,
    'ApiKey': bundle.authData.ApiKey
  }
}

return z.request(options).then((response) => {
 response.throwForStatus();
 const result = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
 result.id = result.CustomFields;
 return [result];
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

​

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely possible! Unless your subscriber data actually needs to be a separate trigger (which is unlikely, since you probably just trigger off new contacts), it can just be a function. Try something like:

```js
const subscriberPerform = async (z, bundle) => {
  const emailResponse = await z.request({
    url: "https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Subscribers?PageSize=1",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-API-KEY": bundle.authData.ApiKey, // does this need to be both places?
    },
    params: {
      ApiKey: bundle.authData.ApiKey, // does this need to be both places?
    },
  });
  // requires core version 10+
  const email = emailResponse.data.email;

  const emailDataResponse = await z.request({
    url: `https://edapi.campaigner.com/v1/Subscribers/${email}/Properties`,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "X-API-KEY": bundle.authData.ApiKey,
    },
    params: {
      email_address: bundle.inputData.email_address, // lots of duplicated data here
      ApiKey: bundle.authData.ApiKey,
    },
  });

  return [emailDataResponse.data.SOMETHING];
};
```

That's the general idea. These JS functions may not need to be triggers at all, depending on how you're using them.

One last note - you don't want to perform this extra lookup every time you poll for new contacts; that's wasteful. If you're doing that, check out [dehydration](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md#dehydration).

Comment: I think that we have made some progress and are able to get the data and merge them together, but it is simply a matter of formatting the array data, which is what we are working on now.